# How to exclude some installed software using Remastersys

Tags: remastersys

I am preparing a distributable ISO by using Remastersys 3.0.4-1 with "Dist" option
I dont wish to include some installed software in my output ISO image, is it possible?

I wish to exclude remastersys software in my output ISO
**Please see below picture**

[image: a busy cat]
<sub>(source: [imgbox.com](https://i.imgbox.com/acyXeJef.png))</sub>

I would appreciate your help

Answer (score 0):

Here you exclude directories and files.

Just enter the directory names or files (path needed) separated with a space.

For example: `/home/mitch/downloads/` `/home/mitch/Downloads/<file_name>`

Comment: is there a way to do this in CLI ?